Are there free objective tools that can be used for assessing pronunciation?
The "standard" would be against that of native speakers.
I'm also interested in fluency and intonation.

Ask a native speaker for help.

Could you please reword your question to clarify what exactly you mean? Assessing your own pronunciation as a self learner? Assessing a learner's pronunciation (as a teacher or instructor)? And for which language?
